# What is to be done with all the sources disabled on upgrade?

Tags: updates, repository

After upgrading from Lubuntu 12.04 to 12.10 I see **a lot** of repositories disabled in the list of sources.

[image]

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: I'd suggest deciding whether you actually want all of those PPAs, and cleaning up a bit - some of the repositories are for Karmic.

Comment: @mikewhatever: can i enable all those disabled specified as `quantal`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have *a lot of* external repositories enabled. All external repositories are being disabled in the upgrade<sup>1</sup> process to avoid conflicts and you were probably warned about this by the upgrade manager.

There's no simple "yes, enable them all" or "no, don't do it" advice to give here. And this is the reason why the upgrade manager left you to fix it manually.

After a successful upgrade, check for the availability of packages for 12.10 in the entries and re-enable them *in case you still want to use them*<sup>2</sup>. Make sure to select the right release channel, e.g. `quantal` for PPAs. The upgrade manager has already replaced `precise` with `quantal` for you in this case I assume.

Some external ones with a less specific release channel like `stable` might need adjustments if they are relying on `precise` shared library versions. From the screenshot I see just Chrome and Opera, these will probably just work by enabling without modifications. I also see some `karmic` there still... this might be broken for a longer period of time.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Irrelevant whether repositories providing packages for the new release. You'll have to fix it up manually.</sub>
<sup>2</sup> <sub>PPAs are frequently used 1) to fix bugs not in Ubuntu main yet at the time 2) to provide software not included in Ubuntu main archives. This may not be relevant anymore in the new release.</sub>

Comment: can i keep all those disabled that specify `quantal`?

Comment: @cipricus If you don't want them, you can keep them disabled, of course. If packages were installed using these PPAs before, then you might want to get rid of them too as you won't be able to receive updates on them anymore.

Comment: i meant: can i enable them? and being disabled upon upgrade means that even enabled they do not provide upgrades in quantal? why are they specified as quantal then?

Comment: @cipricus See my [update](http://askubuntu.com/posts/236770/revisions).