# Why re-enabled sources are still marked as "disabled on upgrade to quantal"?

Tags: 12.10, updates, lubuntu, repository

After having a lot of software sources disabled on upgrade to Lubuntu quantal (see question [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/236762/47206)) I have decided to re-enable most of them, which I did, without problems, except that the note that they were "disabled on upgrade to quantal" is still there. 
[image]
Why is that, and what does that mean at this point?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a simple comment that is added by the upgrade procedure, and it does not have special meaning. So you can edit the source and clear the comment. 
[image: edit a software source]